# file_get_contents: "Unable to find the wrapper "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"

Tags: denwer, php

Нужно получить XML-файл по URL.
Использую

```
file_get_contents
```

-выскакивает вот такое.

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

стоит.
Работаю под Денвером.

Как ещё можно его получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, нужно было поставить

```
allow_url_include = On
```

и... перезагрузить весь компьютер, Restart denwer было недостаточно

Answer (score 0):

Ругается на настройки php.ini, видимо - узнайте, где именно лежит конфигурационный php.ini: в папке windows или php, и настройте тот.

Comment: php.ini был только один - в папке php5